# continuous function without an extension to an open set.

Tags: general-topology

What’s a subset $A\subset \mathbb R$ and a continuous $f:A \to  \mathbb R$ that doesn’t extend to an open $U$ containing $A$?

This question has no motivation.  It just occurred to me, and i couldn't find an example, but it seems natural enough. I feel like one probably exists, since otherwise there is a very strong extension theorem i haven't heard of.  But that's not that unlikely either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be irrational numbers, then there's a function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ with no extension to a continuous function $f:A\cup \{q\}\to\mathbb{R}$ for any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, we cannot extend it to a neighbourhood of $A$.

For $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ let $f_q = \begin{cases} 0 & x < q \\ 1 & x > q\end{cases}$, $f_q:A\to\mathbb{R}$, and enumerate rationals as $(q_n)_{n\geq 0}$. Then the function $f = \sum_{n\geq 0} 2^{-n}f_{q_n}$ is continuous as uniform limit of continuous functions.

But if $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x_n, y_n$ are sequences of irrational numbers such that $x_n < q < y_n$ and $x_n, y_n\to q$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (f(y_n)-f(x_n)) = 2^{-m}$ where $q = q_m$, so $f$ doesn't have an extension to $A\cup \{q\}$.

However, note that any continuous function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ extends to some continuous function $f:B\to\mathbb{R}$ for a $G_\delta$-set $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ (a result related to the famous Lavrentiev's theorem).

Comment: very cool construction. thank you